# Multiple records of model in a single form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

I would like to create a form which works in the connection table between a "**M:N**" relation.
So the user is able to add multiple rows of a **parent model** in one form.

Can some help me to bring this working? What should be the associations?
My problem is the same like [here](https://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/3fea3a90e32c1ece).

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are trying to do some nesting have you tried these tuts from railscasts

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Also checkout this for some guidance on the types of relations you want

http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many

Comment: Please have a look at my question. I updated it with a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do that manually inside the controller without rails' form_for helper.

Thats actually what the second part of the answer to the question you linked to suggests.

Just like the answer mentions, giving `<input>` fields names ending with `[]` (e.g. `<input type="text" name="field[]">`) results in that field being an array in the params hash inside the controller.